# Viewgroup inside a TextInputLayout makes floating label not working

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-textinputlayout

I am using android TextInputLayout to show floating label on EditText.

But i want to show a ProgressBar on left of EditText thus i have added a relative layout inside the TextInputLayout and EditText inside that Relative Layout.

by doing so,The floating label does not work.

If i remove in the relative layout from the TextInputLayout and make the EditText direct children of it,Then it Works.

So does EditTExt needs to be a direct children of TextInputLayout and if so,how can we put another widget to EditTexts left like ProgressBar.

As TextInputLayout inhertis from LinearLayout,adding children to it will add children vertically but i want to add views on top of EditText.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/holderName"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 android:layout_width="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/etField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Name"


    >
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/primary"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: where is your code sir?

Comment: I have posted the code,even though the code has FrameLayout as children,not relative layout as per the question.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to wrap the `TextInputLayout` and `ProgressBar` with `FrameLayout` like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/holderName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Name" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/primary"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is not available. In `addView()` it directly searches for the `EditText`.

Here is the code

```
@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    if (child instanceof EditText) {
          mInputFrame.addView(child, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(params));

          // Now use the EditText's LayoutParams as our own and update them to make enough space
          // for the label
          mInputFrame.setLayoutParams(params);
          updateInputLayoutMargins();

          setEditText((EditText) child);
    } else {
          // Carry on adding the View...
          super.addView(child, index, params);
    }
}
```

So, the first child must be of type `EditText`.

If you want that functionality then inside `RelativeLayout` take your `TextInputLayout` and the `ProgressBar` and set the positions of Progressbar